# Word for a team whose members play perfectly together all having different talents

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, adjectives, context

I am looking for a word that describes a team whose members all have different talents, excel at those talents perfectly and are able to, despite their different skillsets, work together seamlessly and effortlessly.

Like a machine or motor whose gear-wheels are perfectly optimized for each other never really creating too much friction but nevertheless the whole motor together roars like a hungry and angry tiger when you hit the gas.

The words well-cooperating, well-established and well-coordinated are not exactly what I am looking for, the German term "eingespielt" does reflect what I mean perfectly, since the word I am looking for should be used in a playful context. Playful to the attitude of the team members for each other yet damn serious about the outcome of the work the team accomplishes.

The context in what I am looking for this word is a sentence similar to this for example.

"A [word here] team of diverse/varying talents trying hard to deliver the next seminal world changing climate control prodigy app."

Comment: I don't know that there's a single adjective that carries all that nuance, but the noun-phrase *well-oiled machine* is a common idiom meaning exactly this. In your context, *The team is **a well-oiled machine** of diverse* etc.

Comment: Look up *concinnity, synergy, harmonious *.

Comment: **well-oiled machine** is just what I am looking for, thanks heaps!

Comment: That's known as **teamwork**.

Comment: @HotLicks Yeah **teamwork** is what I thought of as well, though in the context of the _slogan_ with regards to IT or engineering **well-oiled machine** sounds great to me, however yes **teamwork** sure is an option.

Answer (score 2):

The adjective I would use to describe such a team is **well-orchestrated.** An [orchestra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestra) is a team where everyone performs different functions (by playing different instruments), but works well with others in the group as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

> "A ***harmonious*** team of diverse/varying talents trying hard to deliver
>   the next seminal world changing climate control prodigy app."

ODO:

> **[harmonious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/harmonious)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> 1.1 Forming a pleasing or consistent whole.
>
> ‘You only get another go as ‘you’ if you manage to reconcile all the
>   differences between these spirits and blend them into a harmonious
>   whole with the ability to create.’

Answer (score 0):

***Complementary***

Used with your example sentence:

*A complementary team of diverse/varying talents trying hard to deliver
the next seminal world changing climate control prodigy app.*

You can see this phrase at work in [the article](https://www.tintup.com/blog/why-you-need-a-complementary-team-of-different-skills-when-you-start-a-company/):

> Why You Need a Complementary Team of Different Skills When You Start a
>   Company.

courtesy of tintup.com.

Interestingly as [this article](http://leadchangegroup.com/the-value-of-a-complementary-team/) explains from leadchangegroup.com, complimentary refers to behaviors as well as skills: -

> Complementary Fits Extend To Behaviors As Well.
>
> If you have a basketball team of all great shooters, but none who want
>   to pass to their teammates or help play defense, what percentage of
>   games do you truly expect to win? A team of people whose behaviors
>   fits together works more effectively than those who try to stand on
>   their own.

Comment: You have confused *complimentary* and *complementary*. Those are two completely different words. Please look up the real definitions of both of these and then edit your answer to remove the wrong one.

Comment: The definition and references are all to the correct word 'complementary' -- only the introduction, your example sentence and a subsequent typed passage have **complimentary** as a possibly inadvertent misspelling. The auto-correct feature in mobile typing software has often tripped me up in this manner. HOWEVER, *complimentary* is an entirely different word and an EL learner may go away with a misconception, so please correct as appropriate!